# Oracle SQL Select where clob field is not empty/null

Tags: sql, oracle10g, clob

I am trying to get rows from an archive database for populating a test environment DB. I need rows where a specific field called "AUDIT_LOG" which is CLOB cannot be empty null.

I have tried the following simple select statements but I get

> ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB

The statements I have tried:

```
SELECT * FROM SIEBEL.S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE AUDIT_LOG = ''

SELECT * FROM SIEBEL.S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE AUDIT_LOG != NULL

SELECT * FROM SIEBEL.S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE AUDIT_LOG = 0
```

Does a NULL in CLOB equate to an empty character string. I have a feeling maybe length can be used for the column.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to check NULL, regardless of datatype, you use `IS NOT NULL` or `IS NULL`

```
WHERE AUDIT_LOG IS NOT NULL
```

But keep in mind that for CLOBs, an `EMPTY_CLOB()` has no characters but is not the same as NULL.  If you want to exclude `EMPTY_CLOB()`, use @user3837669's answer that uses a `LENGTH` comparison.

Comment: Thanks, I still think I am using mysql sometimes.

Comment: To be safe, should we check both the length and for nulls? `length(plussgeojson) > 0` `or` `plussgeojson is null` ... Or does checking the length also exclude nulls too?

Answer (score 9):

```
SELECT * FROM SIEBEL.S_AUDIT_ITEM WHERE length(AUDIT_LOG) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above methods worked for me in Oracle 10g: 
I have to write it in a bad way:

`select * from SIEBEL.S_AUDIT_ITEM where to_char(AUDIT_LOG) != 'null' ;`